# Signal Detector (UHF Field Strength Meter)

Tags: led, rf, circuit-analysis, signal

after some reading I ended up finding a relatively basic FSM, using a antenna, an LC circuit to tune to a specific frequency, and a RF diode and final a ammeter to measure signal strength.

My target frequency is around 500Mhz and I used the resonant frequency equation for LC circuits to calculate a hypothetical L and C.

My big question basically is, is this even going in the right direction? and if there are anything I should change about the values of my components and/or antenna. Also would I be able to replace the ammeter with a typical LED to judge the strength of the signal instead?

If this is completely wrong, please dont hesitate to say so.

I have attached the basic circuit schematic below with my calculations.
[image]

Comment: Nothing at all? :(

Comment: Where did you find that circuit? It looks a lot like a simple AM demodulator which probably  isn't what you are trying  to do at 500MHz (or is it?). Something like this might be better http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/FieldStrengthMeterMkll/FieldStrengthII.html

Comment: Just wanted to make sure I get the question - you want an FSM for ~500MHz, not to detect a signal whose carrier is 500MHz, right? (Two way different ways to detect a signal).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will work without some gain in the system.  Note that the circuit pointed out by @geniass uses multiple transistor stages before approaching an LED.  Unless you have a very very sensitive ammeter, I don't think it will register the current generated by the raw RF signal.